# JQuery UI - Cloned Tabs - not switching tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am cloning a JQuery UI Tabs element.  The tabs are being created OK from the cloned instances, but I can't change the tabs on the instances.  The original tabs element works fine.

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();

$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#tabs').clone().appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='tabs'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1">aa</div>
  <div id="tab2">bb</div>
  <div id="tab3">cc</div>
</div>
<button id='button'>Create Tabs</button>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/px2cjt3r/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-initilize the cloned tabs

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();

$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#tabs').clone().appendTo('body').tabs();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='tabs'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1">aa</div>
  <div id="tab2">bb</div>
  <div id="tab3">cc</div>
</div>
<button id='button'>Create Tabs</button>
```

I would also, replace the `id` of the new tabs to avoid 2 elements with the same `id`.